# First value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT top(100)
    isnull(status, '') as status,
FROM table 1 LEFT JOIN
    table 1 ON table 2 = status LEFT JOIN
```

Table 2 has multiple records with different status.

Currently this query (or a more detailed one I have written) returns multiple status if multiple status exist in the table.

So I need to return only 1 record based on the hierarchy listed below.

Should I be looking at firstvalue?

return

```
1st W -     
2nd X - 
3rd C -
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use "select top(1)" instead of "select top(100)".

Comment: Thanks the top 100 was only for a test. The full data is +400k records

Comment: Your query is not valid SQL. Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text, to clarify your question.

Comment: You use a left join - so update your logic with the obvious use case where there is no related row in table 2. Don't assume. Writing requirements is not as easy as many think.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things I noticed in your query,

1. Are you left joining with the same table? `from table1 left join table1`?
2. When you mentioned  'W', 'X', 'C'  is that status? If yes, then if you are looking for specific status you can add `where status = 'W'` in your query.
3. If you are looking 'W','X','C' in the exact order then its custom ordering, where query needs to be modified.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
ORDER BY case when status = 'W' then 1
              when status = 'X' then 2
              when status = 'C' then 3
              else 4
         end asc
```

Please take input from above query and fix it in your query. If not working then more clarification required.

Comment: and I am looking to do the 3rd option.

Comment: If there a W return that. If there is a X and a C return the X over the C. Should i use First Value function?

Comment: Simple fix for your problem is write a custom sql function. Call the custom function in your select query.